# Office 365 Provider Hosted app Deployment in Azure

Tags: azure, office365

I deployed Office 365 app into azure.. and it is working fine when i deploy with F5 in visual studio..

But the problem is that i am not able to visit app directly with link `http://xyz.azurewebsites.net/` because it is a SharePoint app it requires `{StandardTokens}`.

I tried this but no luck.. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When developing a provider hosted app in SharePoint, you need to access the app through SP, so your code will get the authentication token and execute all your code to retrieve data from SP through the API. **You do not need to access the app through the URL**. this is **not the intent of provider hosted app**. The provider hosted app gives you the flexibility to host your app outside the SP farm (which is in your case in Azure) and integrate properly with Azure AD for exchanging required token to develop against the SP API.

Check out this link that gives a step of step walkthrough for working with provider hosted apps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx

Hope this helps.